# Gulp browserify/browser-sync unexpected token when compiling SASS

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-sass

I have created a `gulpfile.js` which works fine so far but as soon I try to add  `browser-sync` and I change my `.scss`-file I get this error `ParseError: unexpected token` and I have no clue why this happens. Another thing is, that even though in my `server.js` I have set `app.listen(3000)` it opens a window with `localhost:3001`???

Here is my `gulpfile.js`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
   connect = require('gulp-connect'),
   uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
   sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass'),
   webserver = require('gulp-webserver'),
   browserify = require('gulp-browserify'),
   browserSync = require("browser-sync").create();


  gulp.task('browser-sync', function(){
     browserSync.init({
        server: {
           baseDir: "./public"
        }
     });
  })

 gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return sass('public/scss/*.scss')
    .pipe(browserify())
    .pipe(uglify()) 
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'));
 });

 gulp.task('watch', function(){
   gulp.watch('public/scss/*.scss', ['styles'])
 })

gulp.task('webserver', function() {
  gulp.src('root')
  .pipe(webserver({
    livereload: true,
    directoryListing: true,
    port: 3000
  }));
}); 

gulp.task('default', ['webserver', 'watch', 'browser-sync'])
```

So, does anyone know what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: Does it tell you what line / file the error happened?

Comment: it tells me the error comes from the first line in my .scss file: `body {`

Comment: Can you update your question and add the css file so that the error can be reproduced?

Comment: I'm not sure, but shouldnt you read files before and then use sass? `gulp.src('files.scss').pipe(sass().on('error',sass.logError))`. Also try to add `gulp-plumber` it might help you to find out what is the real problem